# Google Drive API v3 - Import CSV in Sheet - Is it possible to disable smart conversion?

Tags: csv, google-drive-api

Thanks to the API, we can create an empty Sheet file and then fill it with CSV data.
In my CSV data, strings are surrounded by double quotes (").
In these data, there are barcodes like "0212345678901".
In the Sheet file, the string 0212345678901 is converted in number, so the first 0 disapear … That is not correct.
In a CSV file, if a string is surrounded by double quotes, it shoul'd remain a string …

My data are imported in 2 steps :

1. I create a new empty Sheet file with API. The API return the created file id.

   1. POST => `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files`
   2. body :

      ```
      {
        'name': 'aFilename',
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
        'parents': [idFolder]
      }
      ```
2. I update the file (with a PATCH REST call) with the previous returned id. The content is my CSV data.

   1. PATCH => `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/${file['id']}?uploadType=media`
   2. Headers : Authorization + 'Content-Type' : 'text/csv'

So, I have two questions :
1 : Is it possible to disable the smart conversion?
2 : Or, is there a way to specify that a string must remain a string (like in Excel if we start a formula with a simple quote ')?

Sample :

```
"21/12/2018 17:02:06","3614950268815",1  
"21/12/2018 17:04:28","0212345005507",1  
"21/12/2018 17:32:10","3614950268891",1  
"21/12/2018 17:32:52","3614950268099",1  
"21/12/2018 17:34:36","3614950268105",1
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: The answer gave by Tanaike is what I've done before having his answer …
I took a mix between the first and the second options and used Spreadsheet API.
I only changed my second step and called the Sheet API endpoint (spreadsheets.values.update) and add a simple quote before the barcode.
I did this because initial data are stored in an array and now I do not have to create the CSV string …

Comment: Thank you for your additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about these modifications? There are 3 patterns in your situation. I think that there are several answers. So please think of this as one of them.

#### 1. Add an apostrophe

In this pattern, by adding an apostrophe to the CSV data, it can be used as a string value. Please add an apostrophe to the CSV data and update the Spreadsheet using the modified CSV file. I think that this is most simple in these 3 patterns.

```
"21/12/2018 17:04:28","'0212345005507",1
```

or

```
"21/12/2018 17:04:28",'0212345005507,1
```

#### 2. Use a method of spreadsheets.values.update in Sheets API

In this pattern, a method of spreadsheets.values.update in Sheets API is used to the created Spreadsheet.

Endpoint:

```
PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### spreadsheetId ###/values/### sheetName ###?valueInputOption=RAW
```

Request body:

```
{
 "values": [
  [
   "21/12/2018 17:02:06",
   "0212345005507",
   "1"
  ]
 ]
}
```

#### 3. Use a method of spreadsheets.create in Sheets API

In this pattern, a method of spreadsheets.create in Sheets API is used. In this case, both creating spreadsheet and putting values can be done by one API call.

Endpoint:

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets
```

Request body:

```
{
 "sheets": [
  {
   "data": [
    {
     "rowData": [
      {
       "values": [
        {
         "userEnteredValue": {
          "stringValue": "21/12/2018 17:02:06"
         }
        },
        {
         "userEnteredValue": {
          "stringValue": "0212345005507"
         }
        },
        {
         "userEnteredValue": {
          "numberValue": 1
         }
        }
       ]
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ],
 "properties": {
  "title": "### filename of spreadsheet ###"
 }
}
```

#### Note:

- In the case of patterns 2 and 3, Sheets API puts the value of `0212345005507` by automatically adding an apostrophe. When you see the cell, it's `'0212345005507`.

#### References:

- [spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)
- [spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create)

If these were not the result you want, I'm sorry.